# Calculating the number of days between two dates using joda time api

Tags: java, date, jodatime, date-difference

I have two dates. I am getting dates from database like this:-

```
Date d = new Date();
Date dTarget = finance.getTargetDate();
```

at the moment my d is `2017-12-29` and dTarget is `2017-12-31`

Now i am trying to calculate the number of days in between them using Joda time api. I expect number of days to be 2 but at the moment I am getting 1, which I think is incorrect.

My timezone is `UTC+5:45`

```
     //joda initital datetime
    DateTime intdt = new DateTime(new Date());
    DateTime targetDt = new DateTime(dTarget);

    int noOfDays = Days.daysBetween(intdt,targetDt).getDays();
    System.out.println(noOfDays);
```

Am I finding the difference between two dates correctly? Why is it not showing 2 for this case?

Comment: Try this Days.daysBetween(intdt.toLocalDate(), targetDt.toLocalDate()).getDays()

Comment: You could try this `Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(start), new LocalDate(end)).getDays();`

Comment: thanks after using Localdate it is now showing 2 days. now i think i am getting differences correctly.  thanks vts and noob programmer.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. You can assume any basic date-time question has already been asked and answered.  Tip: `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( LocalDate.parse("2017-12-29" ) , LocalDate.parse("2017-12-31" ) )` is `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 Days.daysBetween(intdt.toLocalDate(), targetDt.toLocalDate()).getDays()
```

The `LocalDate` class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String inputString1 = "23 01 1997";
String inputString2 = "27 04 1997";

try {
    Date date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
    Date date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
    long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    System.out.println ("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Even less when they are already using something better, in this case Joda-Time.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).